# Simple SQL concatenation

Tags: sql-server, concatenation

how to concatenate names in MS SQL SERVER? Is there any other way to concatenate rather than using + ? Since I am a beginner to learn database concepts can anyone help me by providing your valuable answers?

Comment: ANSI SQL has `||`, e.g. `'first' || ' ' || 'last'` becomes `'first last'`.

Comment: Please specify the `RDBMS` you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use:

```
SELECT Tablename, CONCAT(fieldName1,', ',fieldName2,', ',fieldName3) AS name FROM Tablename;
```

Comment: Which is another very product specific answer - to a question with no dbms specified.

Answer (score 1):

[Read This Link For Better Understanding](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-concat-function.htm)

SQL CONCAT function is used to concatenate two strings to form a single string. Try out the following example:

SQL> **`SELECT CONCAT('FIRST ', 'SECOND');`**

Answer (score 0):

```
 CONCAT('FIRSTNAME ', 'LASTNAME');
```

Comment: Which is a very product specific answer - to a question with no dbms specified.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: Use the CONCAT Function of SQL

**Description**: Let suppose you have the table of employees consist of first_name and last_name, so in order to get all employees with the concatenation of their first and last names you may use the following query

**Query**

SELECT
    CONCAT (first_name, last_name)
FROM
    employee_tbl;

Comment: Which is a very product specific answer - to a question with no dbms specified.

Answer (score -1):

select firstname + '' + lastname  as FullName from employee

Comment: Which is a very product specific answer - to a question with no dbms specified.

Comment: I agree with @jarlh